# Why is a datasheet graph copy without attribution considered stealing when it does not violate IP or copyrights?

Tags: discussion

@DaveTweed recently deleted my Answer

- These images have no personal author and the legal copyright details in the datasheet do not prohibit copying for educational purposes.
- No Intellectual Property was being stolen.  After all, they want you to advertise their products.  But I did not need any specific reference as it was irrelevant to the question.

Even I recall @Kortuk once said "more attributions to datasheet images would be NICE TO HAVE" meaning not necessary according to the rules of attributions"  **Although his name is not searchable is not searchable to find this comment** for some reason. I am paraphrasing and he did not capitalize.

Since my answer does not infringe on Intellectual Property usage and is not restricted in the legalese for copying for educational purposes, I assert your actions and the assumptions that any image without a citation or attribution is illegal or even in bad taste.

It is far different from copying a personal graph in Wikipedia which has a requirement for attribution.

This is a commercial part and sharing information does not violate their copyrights or Intellectual Property.

In my opinion, this is action ignoring the fact that it is a commercial document free to the public to share as they see fit for educational/non-profit purposes and Dave was ignorantly applying 1 rule for all images.

Furthermore, I resent @ElliotAlderson 's accusation I was stealing anything, when the burden of proof is his and there is none since it is not "personal" nor assuming I have any IP rights.

Maybe the rules need updating or Dave needs to be more consistent with his actions to everyone for every image on this site.

This is not personal, rather a commercial datasheet for non-profit educational use. Or is someone profiting from my answers that I dont know about?

[Gate and routing delays as a function of voltage and temperature](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395189/gate-and-routing-delays-as-a-function-of-voltage-and-temperature/395984?noredirect=1#comment972772_395984)

Answer (score 8):

Citation and Copyright are two different issues, and you're confusing them.  Just because you are not impinging on Copyright, either because there is no valid copyright or through Fair Use, has nothing to do with the requirement for citation.

We cite to make it clear where the work is coming from, not because it makes it align with requirements under copyright.

Comment: When it is clear that it comes from say an ST datasheet and the document has no description or follow-on or relevant info to ASICs for PTC thermal behaviour, your assumptions are incorrect making the argument fallacious. -1 When I stated they were google images and I tossed them from hundreds of similar ones, none of which were more relevant than the other, it would take me far longer to find the exact same ones go to the site, find the datasheet link  than anyone to see for themselves, yah the datasheet is not relevant but the characteristic is common.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I sit on a board of academic honesty. I participate in hearings involving proper attribution of sources all the time.  I have training in such matters.  I don't hold web forums to nearly the same standards, but I do know what I'm talking about.  This is silly.  Put a line in your answer saying where the figures came from, and then request that the mods undelete the answer.  Your answer will be better, and will satisfy those (properly) asking for attribution.  FWIW,  it is NOT clear to those who need the info the most that this comes from a datasheet.

Comment: The question was not relevant to any specfic FET.   Most FETs have this behaviour maybe he  could read a book to find out why or just accept this is why ASIC have this characteristic of speed vs timing.

Comment: I resent @ElliotAlderson 's accusation I was stealing anything and you drawing attention to this by deleting it.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, yes, your answer clearly has value, and if you attribute your figures, people will see it and get that value.

Comment: I understand the value of attribution and use them often, in this case, it has less added value than the google image search for the same keywords I used.

Comment: Then, by all means, flag the comment you're finding offensive.  I didn't delete you're answer, I'm responding to your question.

Comment: I did and Dave did as I stated in 1st line and he is not supportive and only deflects the issue with bias. Scott I value your opinions.

Comment: FYI this was my reply to the request for attribution after my explanation https://www.google.com/search?q=variation+of+RdsOn+vs.+temp&num=50&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji-4js98XdAhWEzIMKHVPTBjsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=652

Comment: If you argument is true and mine is true, then Dave Tweed has alot of answers and questions with images that have no citations to avoid bias towards me.  and Elliot should apologize for rudely accusing me of "Stealing" when I was not.

Comment: You were accused of plagiarism, of which you continue to admit that's exactly what you did. You were never addressed rudely by Elliot in this post.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I opened your link to Google Image Search, and now I'm lost since I don't know which site you took the image from. That's certainly not a proper citation. What's the difficulty of mentioning the source of the image? How can the community be sure that the image you took is the correct one, not the manipulated one from shady websites?

Comment: The fallacy in your argument @ScottSeidman is the references were not necessary "We cite to make it clear"  All CMOS logic families and ASIC's have the same PTC characteristic as all the examples of FETS that have the advantage of showing this graph and illustrating that answer of mine.  It was a pedantic request and a redirection from me to say it was irrelevant and teaching person how to fish for more image examples with no contradiction.  But I understand your logic and am not confused as you said. It was an inclusive example, not exclusive. Your premises are false.

Comment: @W5VO again I disagree strongly that using a datasheet graph in an answer is plagiarism. That is absurd. And to assume I don’t understand these word definitions is insulting too. As it is you who does not understand the lack of person to reference in a data sheet nor  is it presumptuous that I created it. Obvious isn’t it?

Comment: @Tony That is the standard that ***I*** am held to in my work. If you use data or ideas from a source, you cite it. I have cited datasheets (with no specific person as an author) in my published work, and I would have been punished for ethical and legal violations - regardless of my intent, regardless of how "harmful" it actually was. If you're going to continue to argue that what you did wasn't plagiarism, I'm concluding that this discussion has hit a dead end, and that you are guilty of blatant and unrepentant plagiarism.

Comment: Then you contradict the definition

Comment: It does not pass the criteria test, where you have repeatedly ignored my points instead of commenting on them, is it stubbornness or ignorance ? Is this held to the same standard as a publication? Not. Do others get the same biased derogatory treatment for incited datasheet extracts. No . Is this bias targeted inflammatory response from admins? Yes

Answer (score 6):

The rule here is that you must [cite your sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Among other things, it allows a reader to dig deeper for details you might have left out.

Comment: There are no more details in any of the datasheets about FET thermal resistance characteristics other than the graphs. For that you have to find a textbook.  It was a simple explanation of complex FET chips (ASIC's) from discrete characteristics in commercial FETs.  Your bias is noted. -1

Comment: Dave Question can you "cite the name of the original author"  If not then this rule does not apply if the legalese does not prohibit copies like books do.

Comment: If you put as much effort into adding the citations as you are arguing about it, this wouldn't be an issue at all. Your choice...

Comment: I said I tossed the Google images links. Get over it and stop being biased and inconsistent about this "rule" and denying I am correct that this does not apply.

Comment: If you would like to prove your point above, find my datasheet images on Google and see how long it takes.  Next ok, but this time does not warrant deleting an answer or make it any better to include them.

Comment: @Tony Google image links aren't actual references - you need to cite the page the image came from. Just linking to search results is a very temporary fix as the search results change over time.

Comment: I did not do that in my answer just the comment, so I understand your point. But my point is the CMOS behaviour has not change since they were invented and unlikely to change with smaller lithography unless some other chemistry is used like Si-Ge-Ind-Ph     . All CMOS has a PTC and ALL CMOS reduces max transition frequency with rising temperature.  So a general quick look at all discrete datasheet curves was just to sho my point. I could have done better to examine the physics why, but tried to keep it simple.  @W5VO TY  My other point is there is no added value to a citation.

Comment: My graphs are obviously not plagiarism., nor do they have author names, so how does your justification for deleting it apply?  Will we expect you to do this for every answer in this forum with an image to show your "fair play"?

Comment: @Tony Unreferenced graphs **are** plagiarism. In fact, they are *obviously* plagiarized because it is clear that *someone else* made them and *we don't know who that is*. If it came from a datasheet, then you reference the datasheet.

Comment: @Tony Regarding this being evenly applied, you're right. This gets brought to moderator attention via flags, and so that's (generally) how we respond. I would be really happy if proper attribution was paid on all images and data sets. If an author of a post is unwilling to add proper attribution, then I think deletion is probably the only tool we (mods) have left.

Comment: If that were the case, I would have followed suit.

Comment: But nor is it a person was it a simple task to find the same exact image references from datasheets, when my point was clear, It is irrelevant and then he was insulting.. But I guess this is what to expect frome users on this site.along with lack of professionalism from lack of support from some admins.

Comment: Even Kortuk said this ...https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/705/links-to-datasheets  But then @DaveTweed is not being nice

Comment: @Tony You were asked nicely to add attribution. You refused, so a moderator was forced to intervene.

Comment: Perhaps the person did not understand my reasons.  Hard to find. Irrelevant, and maybe the moderator misunderstands the meaning of "rquirements for attribution"  Author and IP . Convenience is not a reason nor is misundersanding my reasons on the part of the critic.  Maybe I should have not included where to find examples in my response to look at google images... doh  I did respond nicely , perhaps he misunderstood  > He was insulting , claiming I was equivalent to stealing. WHich part do you not understand? Are you biased?

Comment: @Tony Your response makes me think that you still don't understand what plagiarism means. Wikipedia has a good definition of plagiarism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism . Google is not a source, it is a tool for finding sources. Our citation requirements are tame by comparison to a research paper - IEEE requirements for attribution are the standard that **I** am regularly held to. Your excuse is interesting, but not valid for avoiding attribution.

Comment: PLagiarism is personal copying of intellectual property , not related to illustrations found in a datasheet with the company's name on it where one might consider it as free advertising.  Perhaps you got your assertion backwards.  Read the Etymology again."denote stealing someone else's work "  THere is no SOMEONE here" and it is not personal work. This is a public commercial  document.with no violation of terms.  The real question is my google image response is the other person did not understand the meaning of plagiarism

Comment: nor appreciate when I said it was hard to find anyways and irrelevant to specific examples.  EVERY CMOS PART BEHAVES THIS WAY.  and this is NOT plagiarism.  It is just an irrelevant convenience to include it eg a NICE TO HAVE, not something for DAVE to make a big issue about it and DELETE it and let an insult go standing  Read  that Etymology until you really understand it.

Comment: Again, confusing copyright and plagiarism issues is a common mistake. Why do you think that pictures, data, or figures are immune to plagiarism? How is it advertising if you don't mention where you got the information? If it's hard to find, then that's even more reason for you to have references. If there isn't a *specific* author of a datasheet, then *the company* is the author.

Comment: And just for fun, you're wrong that *all* CMOS behaves that way.

Comment: citation please  (lol)

Comment: Some FETS have an NTC but all CMOS logic {and those} used in ASICs has a PTC ok?

Comment: Again I am not confused about copyright nor plagiarism.  Using an image from a datasheet has nothing to do with plagiarism and is frequently tolerated. Why insult me?  Confusious says... man who attacks with bad logic should have his head read.. for the same reason the RLC image in my recent answer has no citation and I linked to the Wiki site where it explains why.   **There was no person to attribute it to.** Yet obviously I did not create these images, so it not on false pretence, the assumption for plagiarism to be true. Those that do not agree can be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: unfotunately @DaveTweed  your statements are fallacious. *Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted.*  Neither is the work on some ONE and it obviously from a commercial datasheet  (thus no pretense that it is my own) and I disagree that I left out anything from those unknown sites which had those graphs. It is just general FYI info about generally common known behavior ( for those skilled in this art)

Comment: It is also bad form on your part to have done this ( make erroneous admin responses) and single out my answers when so many others do this all the time (since it is not plagiarism.) But if it was relevant you can be sure and should know that I do post links when useful.

Comment: Just my quick input here Tony. The moderators have responded to say they usually act upon flags. Moderators don't go looking through every single question and answer looking for things to delete (maybe they do, but I doubt it).

Comment: @MCG: I've edited out your astoundingly bad advice. We are trying to avoid escalating the issue here.

Comment: @DaveTweed apologies, I guess I responded fairly quickly without thinking it through there. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: OK DAVE BE THAT WAY

Comment: Dave if you deleted my answer because the the truth is accurate but explained poorly. It is a function of mobility and minority carriers why Si FETs are PTC and also depends on Vt.  I would not be offended. But to support this ludicrous argument of plagiarism smacks of inappropriate admin inflammatory interpretation of what plagiarism really means to pretend content is your own, which .I. did not. So your bias is noted.